# PHP - how to display information from specific member from the other table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Good Day GURUS!

I know my sounds indifference but I will try to elaborate as much as I can. I will just want to ask how could I display an information from John Doe (member table) with the other table (ex. book_information). Assuming that there are lot of members in the database the likes of Juan Doe, James Doe and more but I would like to display the information of books which borrowed by John Doe. Sample Illustration is below:

Name: John Doe
Address: Fairy Land
Contact: 225-659

Borrowed Book Information:

### Book Title | Author  | ISBN       | Date Borrowed   | Action

Snow White | Mr Snow | 02-999898  | 09-15-2015      | RETURNED?
The Naked  | G. Bell | 02-910031  | 09-21-2015      | RETURNED?

View Profile Codes

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="margin-top">
        <div class="row">   
            <div class="span12">        
        <?php $get_id = $_GET['id']; ?>

        <?php 
        $query=mysql_query("select * from member where member_id='$get_id'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($query);

?>

            <div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Viewing Profile</strong> of <?php echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']; ?></div>

            <p><?php echo $row['badge']; ?>.jpg" width="90" height="90"></p>
            <p>Name: <strong><?php echo $row['firstname'].", ".$row['lastname']; ?></strong></p>
            <p>Address: <strong><?php echo $row['address']; ?></strong></p>
            <p>Contact: <strong><?php echo $row['contact']; ?></strong></p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>Borrowed Book Information:</p>

            <p>

            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table" id="example">

                            <thead bgcolor="#000000" style="color:#ffffff">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Book Title</th>
                                    <th>Author</th>                                 
                                    <th>ISBN</th>                                 
                                    <th>Date Borrowed</th>                                 
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

            <?php  $user_query=mysql_query("select * from borrow
                            LEFT JOIN member ON borrow.member_id = member.member_id
                            LEFT JOIN borrowdetails ON borrow.borrow_id = borrowdetails.borrow_id
                            LEFT JOIN book on borrowdetails.book_id =  book.book_id 
                            where borrowdetails.borrow_status = 'pending'ORDER BY borrow.borrow_id DESC
                              ")or die(mysql_error());
                                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($user_query)){
                                $id=$row['borrow_id'];
                                $member_id=$row['member_id'];
                                $book_id=$row['book_id'];
                                $borrow_details_id=$row['borrow_details_id'];

                                ?>
                                <tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">


                                <td><?php echo $row['book_title']; ?></td> 
                                <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?> </td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['isbn_no'];?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['date_borrow'];?></td>
                                <td> <a rel="tooltip"  title="Return" id="<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>" href="#delete_book<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>" data-toggle="modal"    class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-check icon-large"></i>Return?</a>
                                <?php include('modal_return.php'); ?>
                                <td></td> 

                                </tr>
                                <?php  }  ?>

            </p>       



            <p><a class="btn btn-info" href="member.php"><i class="icon-arrow-left icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Back</a></p>
            </div>
```

Please help because I can't figured out (just a beginner though). I'm stuck on it.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: somewhere in borrowed table there should be an id of who has it borrowed (or borrow history and return status). And the id would not be John Doe. If it is, you have a schema problem

Comment: I'm Screwed up.. You mean to say that I should have added a new column  in borrowed table? and link it to members ID? thanks for your help

Comment: that is what I am saying. I'll be back in an hr or so, someone else can help ya til then I am sure

Comment: Still can't figured out...

Comment: Type up a bunch of detail by editing question. We don't know enough about the problem to help

Comment: Provide pls your full SQL dump or create table statement for all tables you have so far

Answer (score 0):

You already have a query that links all the tables. Just need to modify the where statement to get the results by user name:

```
select * 
from member 
join borrow ON borrow.member_id = member.member_id
LEFT JOIN borrowdetails ON borrow.borrow_id = borrowdetails.borrow_id
LEFT JOIN book on borrowdetails.book_id =  book.book_id 
where member.firstname = 'John' and member.lastname = 'Doe'
```